# Why am i getting a server error with status 500?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to build and API with express and nodejs. I connected to my mongodb and my api is running on the port correctly but i am having an issue with my first route.

I am trying to do a POST route to register a user. When i try to call this route in postman all my validations work, so the name is required, the email should have an email format and a password should have more than 6 characters. And if one of the validations don´t pass the specific error message to that field is shown. The issue is when all of my fields pass the validations i get Server Error.

This is my users.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const gravatar = require('gravatar');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { check , validationResult } = require('express-validator/');

router.post('/', [
    check('name', 'Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Plese include a valid email').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Please enter a password with 6 or more characters').isLength({min:6})
], 
async (req, res)=> {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).json({ errors:errors.array()}); //400 is for bad requests
    }


    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    try{
        //See if user exists

        let user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if(user){
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg:'User already exists' }] });
        }
    
        //Get users gravatar

        const avatar = gravatar.url(email,{
            s:'200',
            r:'pg',
            d:'mm'
        })

        user = new User({
            name,
            email,
            avatar,
            password
        });
    
        //Encrypt password

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        await user.save();
    
        //Return jsonwebtoken -> this for users to be logged in right after registration

        const payload = {
            user:{
                id: user.id
            }
        }

        jwt.sign(
            payload,
            config.get('jwtSecret'),
            {expiresIn: 360000}, //change to 3600 for production
            (err, token)=>{
                if(err) throw err;
                res.json({ token });
            }
            )

    }catch(err){
        console.error('err.message');
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
    

});

module.exports = router;
```

so in Postman i just added a header of `Content-type` with a value of `application/json`

This is the url:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/users
```

And this is the body i am passing:

```
{
    "name": "mateo ghidini",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

Comment: Change `console.error('err.message');` to this `console.error(err.message);` and show us what you got

Comment: Well, your request handler seems to throw an exception. And in the `catch` you return a 500 status code. But instead of printing the static string `"err.message"` you should probably better log the errors message (or even the complete err object) to see what the actual error is. You could also try attaching a debugger and set a breakpoint in that `catch` clause, so you can inspect the `err`  directly ...

Comment: Did you forget to import your `User` repository? Seems like you reference it on line `let user = await User.findOne({ email });` but it's not imported anywhere.